# React axios.get 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I used the postman for testing my url,and it has response data(It's correct).
Url:http://localhost:8000/api/products/find/6337d5d73ec2c05d7c11bc63(ProductId).
In postman,it could get response data.
I wonder I do give it Bearer token in my **requestMethods.js**,which imported in **/pages/Product.jsx**.

But when I use **the same id in axios.get**,it said error:
*Error:GET http://localhost:8000/api/products/find/6337d5d73ec2c05d7c11bc63 401 (Unauthorized)*
[image]

can someone just help me solve this question?
**In /pages/product.jsx line 145,157 are got tag in the photo.**

Here are my relative Codes:

**requestMethods.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/"
const TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9......"

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

**/pages/Product.jsx**
It's mainly codes of website.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { publicRequest,userRequest } from './requestMethods';

const Product = () => {
    // 回傳路徑
    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);//HERE USE REQUESTMETHODS.JS and it's it sad line:145
                console.log(res.data)
                setProduct(res.data);
            }
            catch { } }
        getProduct();//line 157
    }, [id])
    
}

export default Product
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const productRouter = require("./routes/product");

const cors=require("cors");
dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => console.log("connect"))
    .catch(((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/products", productRouter);//USE THE ROUTES/PRODUCT.JS
app.use("/api/orders", orderRouter);
app.use("/api/cart", cartRouter);
app.use("/api/checkout",stripeRouter)
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
    console.log("Run server")
})
```

**routes/product.js**

```
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const updatedProduct = await Products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: req.body
        }, { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedProduct);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});


//delete
router.delete("/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Products.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json("Products has been deleted.")
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
//get  product
router.get("/find/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Products.findById(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json(product);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
```

**verifyToken.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;

    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err, user) => {

            if (err) 
                res.status(401).json("Token is not valid!")
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    }
    else {
        return res.status(401).json("You are not authentication!" );
    }
}


module.exports = { verifyToken, verifyTokenAndAuth, verifyTokenAndAdmin };
```

Comment: We're missing some information, can you post the "verifyTokenAndAdmin" function?
Anyways, this function is being used as a middleware for "/api/products/find/:id".
I'm gonna assume this function is expecting an auth header, and you're using your "publicRequest" on the frontend instead of your "userRequest".

Comment: Are you sure "req.headers.token" shouldn't be "req.headers.Authorization"? Also you might try logging the error if (err) 
                res.status(401).json("Token is not valid!")

Comment: A 401 suggests that the back end service is not getting the authorization header properly nothing really on the frontend unless it is just not passing it

Comment: Also I would use jwt.io to check if it is expired. If the token is hardcoded and you have been working on this project for a while it might fail validation because it is expired. Can you post the clear text of the access token using jwt.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are using publicRequest axios function which does not include bearer token header. Use userRequest function.

Try using the code below in your axios request from frontend:

```
const res = await userRequest.get("/products/find/${id}");
```

Instead of double quotes use string literal. Stack overflow is using my string literal as code snippet that's why I wrote in double quotes.

Also remove the extra slash after api from BASE_URL like this:

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api"
```

Also check in your verifyToken.js file if you have written the functions verifyTokenAndAuth and verifyTokenAndAdmin which you are exporting. If not then please write those functions in verifyToken.js file and then export because you are using verifyTokenAndAdmin middleware in your api. Also please check that server is running and not crashing before making a request.

Comment: const res = await userRequest.get(`/products/find/${id}`);
It's right!!!thank you so much!!!